# Sonarqube behind nginx reverse proxy redirect projects page not login page

Tags: nginx, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

I have an sonarqube inside a docker container and nginx in the server. My nginx.conf

```
upstream sonarqube {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sonarqube.mydomain.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server{
  server_name sonarqube.mydomain.com;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certificates/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certificates/server.key;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/sonarqube.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/sonarqube.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://sonarqube;
    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
  }
}
```

When I go to "sonarqube.mydomain.com" its redirect to "sonarqube.mydomain.com/projects" not login page. How can i direct to login page when we go to "sonarqube.mydomain.com" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  figure out the issue. In settings of sonarquube force user authentication should be the true. That's why its direct to the projects page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it needs to change context path to sonar.
If you run not in docker - set `sonar.web.context=/sonar` in **sonar.properties**.

If docker - add environment `SONAR_WEB_CONTEXT='/sonar'`

nginx will look like:
[image]
proxy_params:
[image]